# Nginx specific rewrite rule query

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am trying to create a rewrite rule for ngnix to redirect everything request that starts with:
 `/node` (i.e `domain.com/node/something/somthingelse`) to `domain.com:3000/something/somthingelse`.

Could anyone show me how to accomplish that ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is achieved with locations like this:

```
server {
    server_name domain.com;
    location ^~ /node/ {
        rewrite ^\/node\/(.*)$ http://domain.com:3000/$1 break;
    }
}
```

See [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
location /node {
  rewrite /node/(.*)   http://domain.com:3000/$1 ;
}
```